# Safe Contract Signature

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe

Can a Gnosis safe contract be owner of another Gnosis Safe contract ? Does it works ? if it works, how to integrate contract-signature with it ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Simply add the address of a safe as the owner to another safe and it should work normally.

Regarding contract signature, what would you like to do? It should be able to broadcast any transactions like it would with any other Safe. If you are referring to EIP-712 (or EIP-1271), Safe contracts support them natively.

Hope it helps,
Louis